# Support of weak limit

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ in $L^2(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is any domain in $\mathbb R^n$. Is there any relationship between the supports of $u_n$ and $u$? The reason I am asking is that I remember seeing somewhere an assertion that, for a weakly (star) convergent sequence of measures, the support of the limit is a subset of the Kuratowski limit inferior (or superior, I cannot remember exactly) of the supports of the sequence members.

Edit: there is an "obvious" relation, namely $\mathrm{supp}\, u\subseteq \cup_n \mathrm{supp}\, u_n$. I would be interested in something more "optimal".

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so we want something like $\operatorname{supp} u \subseteq \cap_{N=1}^\infty \cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n$. Here we go:

$(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges weakly to $u$, and so does every restricted sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq N}$. $A_N = \{ f \in L^2; \operatorname{supp} f \subseteq \cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp}u_n\}$ is a closed subspace of $L^2$, and closed implies weakly closed. Therefore $u$ needs to be in $A_N$ for each $N$. In particular,

$$ \operatorname{supp} u \subseteq \cap_{N=1}^\infty \cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n.$$

Edit: A sketch of why I think the statement will be wrong if we replace the lim sup by lim inf:

Consider $L^2[0,1]$ and let the functions $f_{k,n}$ be defined by
$$ f_{k,m} = 1_{\big [ \frac{k}{m},\frac{k+1}{m}\big ]}$$
for $m \in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\in \mathbb{N}, 0 \leq k < m$. Enumerate them somehow as $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then $f_n \to 0$ in norm, hence $f_n \to 0$ weakly. Consider
$$ u_n = 1 - f_n.$$
Then $u_n \to 1$ weakly. But on the other hand, for each $x \in [0,1]$ there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that there is an open interval $I(n)$ containing $x$ and $\operatorname{supp} u_n \cap I(n) = \emptyset$. Therefore $\lim \inf \operatorname{supp} u_n = \emptyset$ and $\operatorname{supp} u = [0,1]$.

Comment: True, but there is a relation: $\emptyset \subset [0,1]$ :-). I am more of thinking of the case where the supports of the sequence members wander around inside $\Omega$...

Comment: Alright, in that sense you always have the relation $\operatorname{supp} u \subseteq \cup_{n} \operatorname{supp} u_n$ ;-)

Comment: Yes, the question is if it is possible to put a \cap somewhere there in between....

Comment: I've modified the question to be more precise...

Comment: Ok, I've modified my answer. Maybe this is more what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good! One last thing though: I somehow have in mind this comment about the measures and I think it mentioned the limit inferior of the sets and not the limit superior. This would be problematic since the sets $A_N$ will not be convex anymore if we replace the cup with a cap...

Comment: I added the sketch of an example, which I think shows that the statement is wrong for lim inf instead of lim sup.

Comment: Hm...it looks to me as if $\lim\inf\textrm{supp} f_n=[0,1]$: The functions $f_{n}$ slide to the right and their supports become smaller and smaller, right? Then $\cap_{n=m}^\infty \textrm{supp}  f_n=\textrm{supp} f_m$ and then $\cup_{m=1}^\infty \textrm{supp}  f_m=[0,1]$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, they slide to the right. But after finitely many steps, they always start from the left again and hence slide through $[0,1]$ infinitely many times

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: I think we need to take the closure over $\cup_{n=N}^\infty\mathrm{supp }u_n$, otherwise $A_N$ is not closed....

Comment: $A_N$ is still closed. To see this: $L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n)$ is a Hilbert space (as every $L^2$-space is a Hilbert space). Then we may identify $L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n)$ with $A_N$ by setting the functions just $0$ every outside $\cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n$, and hence $A_N = L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty \operatorname{supp} u_n)$ has to be a closed subspace of $L^2(\Omega)$ since it is a Hilbert space on its own.

Comment: I think the problem is that outside of the essential support of a function, there might be a closed set with empty interior but of full measure, such that the function is not zero. That part will contribute when we pass over to the limit.

Comment: Could you give an example for this? I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly here, but if the interior is empty, how sould taking a closure change anything?

Comment: The essential support of a function $u$ is the complement of the union of all open subsets $\omega\subset\Omega$ such that $u=0$ a.e. in $\omega$. That means, that there might exist a closed set $A\subset(\operatorname{supp} u)^c$ with $\operatorname{int} A=\emptyset$ and $\mathcal H^n(A)>0$, such that $u\neq 0$ in $A$.

Comment: When you have that $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty\operatorname{supp}u_n)$ with $u\in L^2(\Omega)$ it might be that $\| u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}>\|u\|_{L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty\operatorname{supp}u_n)}$ due to this set $A$, so that norm convergence in $L^2(\cup_{n=N}^\infty\operatorname{supp}u_n)$ does not imply norm convergence in $L^2(\Omega)$. As an example for such a set $A$ you can think of a space filling curve (or something fancier like the boundary of the Mandelbrot set).

Comment: Alright, now I see what you mean. But something like this cannot happen, as it contradicts weak convergence. I just consider the real $L^2(\Omega)$-space, the complex case works similar. Assume $u_n \to u$ weakly, hence $u_n - u \to 0$ weakly. Further assume there is some set $A \subset \Omega$ with positive measure such that $u$ is not $0$ a.e. on $A$ (it need not to be closed!) and $A \cap \operatorname{supp}u_n = \emptyset$ for $n \geq N$. We may assume that $A$ is cpt. Then $\int_A |u| > 0$.

Comment: There are measurable subsets $A_{+}, A_{-}$ s.t. $A_{+} = A \cap \{u > 0\}$ a.e., and $A_{-}$ analogously. Then with $f = 1_{A_{+}} - 1_{A_{-}}$, $\langle u_n - u,-f\rangle = - \int_A u_n f + \int_A uf = \int |u| \not \to 0$. This is a contradiction to weak convergence. In the end this is just another proof that $\operatorname{supp} u \subseteq \lim \sup \operatorname{supp} u_n$.

Comment: Ok, I get it! If you modify your answer to refer to our discussion in the comments I will accept it as correct, thanks!

Comment: I'll do that later today! :-)